# JQUERY Select all td cells that are inside a tr with certain style

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, tablerow

How can i change the color of the td cells that are inside a tr with a certain style?

For example:

```
<tr style="display: table-row">
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I have done this so far but it does not work completely:

```
if ($('.mydiv').css('display') == 'table-row') {
   $(this).siblings('td').css("background-color", "white");
}
```

Comment: I would to it with the children() selector. `$("tr").children("td").css("blabla")` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thoughts, though untested, would be:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return this.parentNode.style.display == 'table-row';
}).css('background-color','#fff');
```

As written this will select all `td` elements then filter it to those elements whose parent `tr` has the `style="display: table-row;"`; this does require that the `tr` has the style set in-line, though. Throwing a little more jQuery, however, and you can achieve the same with:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().css('display') == 'table-row';
}).css('background-color','#fff');
```

This will filter the same way, but include CSS set in an external stylesheet (or in the `style` tags in the `head` of the document).

I would, however, reduce the DOM traversal and explicitly work on the `tr` elements only, and use a given class-name to achieve the same:

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') == 'table-row';
}).addClass('hasDisplayTableRow');
```

Which, of course, allows CSS to be used:

```
tr.hasDisplayTableRow td {
    /* css */
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think about it that way!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that for a style, you'd need a class:

```
<tr style="display: table-row" class="myrow">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can style it in css:

```
tr.myrow td{
    background-color: white
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$("tr.myrow td").css({"background-color": "white"})
```

**EDIT** David's answer suggests that it is possible. Although it's clever, the class approach would be more maintainable IMO

Answer (score 0):

Comparing inline styles is not always a good idea.

Instead why don't you add the class to the tr in question so that it will be lot cleaner.

```
.table-row{
   display: table-row;
}
```

Then you can just use this

```
if ($('.mydiv').hasClass('table-row')) {
   $(this).siblings('td').css("background-color", "white");
}
```

Instead of this `<tr style="display: table-row">`

try changing your markup

```
<tr class="table-row">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this through CSS? Here's how I'd do it in JQuery.

```
$("tr[style='<your style value here>'] td").css("background-color", "white");
```